# Getting content carried by reference

Tags: c++, gtk, glib

I have a reference to a string object how can i get the data from it. Here is my sample:

```
string key = "key1";
gpointer somepointer;

GHashTable* myTable;
g_hash_table_insert(myTable,&key1,somepointer);         

GList *keysList = g_hash_table_get_keys(myTable);// here i got keys previously set
keysList = g_list_first(keysList);
string recentKey = (keysList->data);
```

data refers to reference of a string. How can i retrieve the data from the reference

Comment: If `data` is a `string&` (to valid location) then your statement `string recentKey = (keysList->data);` is proper. Have you tried printing or checking it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `keysList->data` is `gpointer`(`void*`), I guess some cast like the
following is needed:

```
string recentKey = *(string*)keysList->data;
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

If data is reference to a string then,

keysList->data returns the string.

```
#include<iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string MyString("ABCD");
    string &MyString2 = MyString;
    char * cstr;

    cout<<"\n"<<MyString;
    cout<<"\n"<<MyString2;

    cstr = new char [MyString.size()+1];
    strcpy (cstr, MyString.c_str());

    cout<<"\n"<<cstr;
    delete[] cstr; 

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by "How can i retrieve the data from the reference?" Have you tried just doing it?

The only data in an `std::string` are the string length and the payload `char*` array.
`keysList->data.length()` will access the length while `keysList->data.c_str()` will access the `char*` array.

Your last statement *is* getting the data from the reference:

```
string recentKey = (keysList->data);
```

This statement creates a full copy of the string. Because it is a copy, any modifications to `recentKey` will not show up in `keysList->data`. Whether that is a good or bad thing depends on your intent.

Comment: But data is void* i tried displaying the value, its is displaying memory reference and not value....